# Как корректно создать запрос с условием?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть бд mysql, в ней таблица users. В таблице естественно пользователи. Есть поле gor. 
Если есть хотя бы один пользователь, у которого gor = MCS, тогда переменная $rel = Фен.

Comment: Ок! Как хотябы вывести количество тех людей у которых поле gor = MSK? А то первый ответ полюбому не корректен

Comment: select count(*) from users where gor='MSK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем из базы сумму строк где `gor = MSK`.
Если сумма строк > 0, делаем что собирались.

Для ленивых:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE `gor` = 'MSK'");
if(mysql_result($result, 0)) {
    $rel = 'Фен';
}
```

Comment: вопрос к про. стоит ли сравнивать `mysql_result` с нулем? по идее должно бы и так прокатить...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php

Возвращает либо string либо FALSE...так что вообще лучше !== FALSE, универсальнее.

Comment: можно и не сравнивать. if(mysql_result($result, 0) > 0) в данной ситуации тоже самое if(mysql_result($result, 0))

Comment: @FLK в данном случае да, но если бы результат 0 или '' был бы верен, но было бы не правильно.

Comment: @Nord001 а разве count() не может *успешно* возвратить ноль? =)

тогда при отсутствии совпадений действие исполнится

**upd** изменил условие в ответе... какашка получилась =\

Comment: @ikoolik 
Я имел ввиду, что mysql_result вернёт (bool)False если ошибка запроса. Иначе конкретный результат. Поэтому лучше и надёжнее сверять не только значение но и тип :)

В вашем примере к конкретной задаче было всё правильно.

Comment: count(*) ноль не вернет успешно ) @Nord001 имел ввиду что возможен запрос в результате которого, при условии выборки одного поля, значение поля может быть равным 0 либо ""

Answer (score 2):

```
    $result = mysql_query("select 'Фен' from users where gor='MCS' limit 1");
if($result){//на случай если пустая выборка
    $rel=current(mysql_fetch_row($result));
}
```

как то так.

Comment: вариант с 'Фен' отлично сработает. да согласен так делать не хорошо, но прежде чем заявлять столь категорично, было бы неплохо проверить )

Comment: @LordySL прочтите выше коммент, и то что вы не знаете синтаксиса mysql еще не означает что можно ставить "-" более сведущим

Comment: Запрос синтаксически верен, вообще-то.

Comment: @LordySL, вы не правы!

Comment: @FLK, @exec дайте ссылку где почитать про такую уличную магию =)

Я вот совсем не вдупляю почему этот запрос верен

Comment: потому что там используеться '' <- строковый литерал, если бы было `` то было бы ошибкой.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html

Comment: @Nord001 ок, ночь на дворе, чет я туплю. Берем таблицу `table` в ней поля: `id`, `name`, `value`.

Запрос:

    select 'Василий' from `table`

что вернет запрос в общем случае?
скажем 'Василий' встречается во всех полях таблицы. В разных строках.

Comment: @ikoolik 
Вернёт n строк 'Василий', где n - кол-во строк в таблице

Comment: ништяк. 

Всем спасибо. =)

Comment: @ikoolik он вернет n строк "Василий" даже если в таблице не будет ни одного поля со значением "Василий"

Comment: @FLK Сколько же строк вернет строк такой запрос???

Comment: Если вы про ответ тов. @FLK, то запрос вернет 0 строк, если нет совпадений `gor = 'MSK'` и одну строку `'Фен'`, если совпадения есть (сколько бы их не было)